# How to resolve a reload loop issue in the frontend when logged in to WordPress multi-site backend admin area

Tags: loop, multisite, wp-admin, htaccess

The issue is the websites stemmed from our WordPress multi-site area going into a reload loop on initial load.

Note,this is not a redirect loop, but the page continually attempts to reload in quick succession and doesn't load on first go.

If you do a hard refresh or press ctrl + F5 the website loads fine. This only occurs when you are logged in as an admin user of the Multi-site environment.

We have attempted to resolve by disabling plugins 1 by 1 including any cache related plugins.

Which leads me to think the issue is with the .htaccess file settings for the multi-site environment?

Relevant part of the .htaccess file is below:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin #
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Can you [edit your question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/301018/edit) to include your `.htaccess` file contents (at least the WordPress-relevant parts of it)? There's a set of sample [`.htaccess` files on the Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/htaccess)—are you sure you're using the correct one for your Multisite installation?

Comment: Thanks Pat. I've now included that. Sorry really should have had that in there to start.